# Types of statuses in Monit service manager

Tags: monit

I'm looking to find out what types of statuses that are available in the Monit Service Manager.

So far I've seen Running, Not Monitored and Accessible, but what else can I expect to see?

I've combed thru the man pages and available documentation to no avail, also used my best google-fu trickery...

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the answer to my question is some thing along the lines of "whatever you set up"? I'm not all that familiar with setting up monit from scratch but instead I'm using a bundled monit instance in an on prem teamchat appliance...

Comment: The status depends on the type of the monitored resource. I think the list is static and not dynamic.